# writing a shader error checker in C

Tags: c, opengl, malloc, shader

hi im writing a simple shader error checker in C to check for errors on compilation and link time. im having a big problem with getting the `glShaderSource()` function to work. i first create space for the code using `malloc(codelength * sizeof(char))` then i attach the source to a created shader object with this line `glShaderSource(shader, 1, (const char **) &code, NULL);`. i belive the problem is with this line. ive even tried changing `NULL` to the length of the code but to no avail. when i try to get info on the shader it returns zero to `glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &compileloglength);` and zero to `glGetShaderiv(shaders[0], GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileloglength);` please donbe t point me to a shader error checker that is already out there, unless it has relevant code because i like doing little projects like these.

Comment: I think you should actually be allocating (codelength + 1) * sizeof (char). OpenGL parses shader strings as C strings (when length is 0, anyway), it will terminate upon the first null character since you are  allocating only enough storage for the length of the shader and not the shader + the null terminator, this could be an issue. Otherwise, what you need to do is allocate an array of integers that store the length of each shader string and pass that for the last parameter.

Comment: Do you issue a `glCompileShader()` before your `glGetShaderiv()` calls?

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure: Do you have a valid OpenGL context created? You need a GLSL capable OpenGL context for those functions you use to work.

If you want to do static GLSL checking without creating a OpenGL context first, you can use the stand alone GLSL compiler of the Mesa project.

Answer (score 0):

You call `glShaderSource` to supply the source code for your shader. So, e.g.

```
char *source =
"varying vec2 texCoordVarying;"
"uniform sampler2D texture;"
""
"void main()"
"{"
    "gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoordVarying);"
"}";

glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
```

Your description suggests you're creating space for the source, not putting anything in it, then offering that unfilled space to OpenGL? If so then it's likely your `malloc` happens to be giving you an empty string. That won't create any build errors because an empty string is a valid shader, it just doesn't do anything. You would likely raise an error at `glLinkProgram` for failing to supply suitable `main()`s.

Comment: im reading the shaders from a file into a piece memory allocated by malloc. i can see the actual code so it writes to the memory properly but seems to fail at my glShaderSoure().

Comment: ya i null commented it. i notice this is kind of looking like a different problem i noticed a while ago if i declared the shaders like so char vshader[] = {"#version 430 core..."}; any fix to this?